# prefixfree javascript not executing

Tags: javascript, css

This [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvo4/euq9t/1/) shows how the CSS is prefix-less.  Example

```
.carousel {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-540px);
```

In Firefox 30, which I assume has fully implemented the CSS3 standardised elements, without prefixes, this renders appropriately (save the small icons for positions 1 and 9).  Everyone's  going to get there one would hope; but reality is many legacy browsers are running out there, like folks dearly hanging on to Snow Leopard (like yours truly).

Thus, time to invoke the prefixfree.js

However, older browsers, such as Safari 5.1 and Chrome 24 - by extension IE an o - are rendering nothing by flat elements overlaying each other.

The [instructions](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) state to only include the js file. But in view of the result...  What am I missing?

Comment: Working fine in jsFiddle once we switch from 'onDomready' to 'no wrap' - http://jsfiddle.net/euq9t/2/. How are you including prefix-free in your actual page?

Comment: via a script link "<script src="/assets/prefixfree.min.js"

Comment: I've tried include prefixfree by both script link and script tag.  It is still not kicking in for prefix-less css.

Comment: I would avoid prefixfree.js because it adds an HTTP request for every CSS file you have, which can be many with a CMS like WordPress. Instead I use http://pleeease.io/play.

Comment: Good for pointing that out.  Mind you, this is a Rails application and in production the entire set of css files will get minified to a single css file.